# ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: xxx, port: 8123; xxx:8123 failed to respond

Tags: clickhouse

We keep getting **"ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: xxx, port: 8123; xxx:8123 failed to respond"** error while executing longer-running queries via JDBC.

Tried to set both **keep-alive-timeout=300** on server and **keepAliveTimeout=300000** on client - but with no effect..

Our test query fails after 15-20 seconds of running (
For short queries we never encountered it, all is ok.

I suppose it is some configuration issue? What should be done to avoid this error?

ClickHouse version is **20.3.8.53**

Comment: try this one - https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/159

Comment: Set 2 more timeouts, as recommended: **jdbc:clickhouse://xxx:8123?keepAliveTimeout=300000&socket_timeout=300000&dataTransferTimeout=300000**

Same error after ~16s ((

Comment: could you send this query directly to CH using [curl](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/) (+ try to enable [sending progress info from CH](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/))? Are there any proxies servers between the client and CH?

Comment: @WiPiton JDBC driver overrides your value in URL by it's own value 30. You have to change it in JDBC settings.

Comment: I am just curious, did you managed to solve this issue? If 'yes' - maybe share your experience in your answer?

Comment: I've set up rest project in SoapUI and tried to do experiments there. With simple queries I have no troubles getting output. With my "hard" query (set 300000ms timeout) I've got very suspicious result - after some time (much less than 300s) there was "connection refused" error.. More than that, shortly after "hard" query failed I've got "connection refused" on simple query too! Then, after some time doing nothing on my side and retrying simple query - voila, it works again. This behaviour is perfectly reproducable. I suppose it's time to dig into CH server logs, am I right?

Comment: New addition - it seems we encountered simple lack of physical memory on CH server, which leaded to consequences described. Will try to expand it.

Comment: Now things getting more interesting ) I've got another error: "Code: 241, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded: would use 9.74 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 1073741824 bytes), maximum: 9.31 GiB (version 20.3.8.53 (official build))" Does it mean I need more server memory?

Comment: I've posted an issue on CH github project https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11217