# Would kettle trigger all database connections when starting a job?

Tags: jdbc, kettle, pdi

An error occurred when inserting data into clickhouse:
`Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

After troubleshooting,it turns out that the **socket got time out during the insertion**.

However, the insertion itself doesn't take much time , **5 mintue at most** which is far less than value of **socketTimeout**.

So,I though it might have something to do with the database connections and kettle's strategy to trigger the connecton.

Here's some info about database connections I have in kettle:

1. I got several database connections
2. All of them are **shared**
3. The database connection accessing to clickhouse was only accessed **at the end of the entire job**

Here's the layout of job:
[image]
Here's the layout of `etl` transformation:
[image]

1. I got data inside the transformation
2. Data flow would be transferred to different sub-transformations according to metatdata
3. The insertion happend at the end of each sub-transformation.

So if it's true that kettle starts all the database connection once the job started,it's make the error I met explainable
strong text

[Here's the link of log file](https://github.com/NiDHanWang/test/blob/922c53b0a3fc3d71e508a2efa3b03abcf71885cc/fact_process.log_20210819),the error mentioned start at line 79542 and the reset connection is call `ck_dw_formal`

Here's the error message:

```
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 9986; Connection reset
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - 
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - 
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:384)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:125)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 9986; Connection reset
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - 
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1331)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:262)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  ... 3 more
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - Caused by: ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseUnknownException: ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 9986; Connection reset
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.getException(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:92)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:56)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:25)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.getInputStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:802)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.executeStatement(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:256)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.executeUpdate(ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.java:165)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1298)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  ... 4 more
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 - Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.getInputStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:776)
2021/08/19 00:27:56 - Table output.0 -  ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Jobs don't trigger all connections. Each job entry will trigger the conection(s) it uses, when it starts (whether a sub-job entry, a transformation, SQL entry, etc.).

Transformations are the same, with a caveat: each step of a transformation opens its connection on initialisation. But as all steps initialise in parallel at the beginning of the execution, all connections will be attempted at start.

If you post your log file (mask away sensitive info) it'll be easier to see what exactly is causing the error and when.

[EDIT] According to the error message you're having the connection reset by the remote host. Another SO  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744347/clickhouse-exception-code-1002-host-xxx-port-8123-xxx8123-failed-to-resp) suggests adding a couple timeout parameters to the connection URL.

Comment: Thanks for reply,[here's the link of log file](https://github.com/NiDHanWang/test/blob/922c53b0a3fc3d71e508a2efa3b03abcf71885cc/fact_process.log_20210819),the error mentioned start at line 79542

Comment: The reset connection is called `ck_dw_formal`